# Eclipse ant task use custom WIX config file (wxs) file instead default wxs file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant, wix

I am using Eclipse 4.5.2 to deploy JavaFX application (JDK 1.8). I want to change an IniFile during the installation. Ant task or JavaFX deploy is generating a wxi and wxs file in temp folder `AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler5060494280971686435\windows`

But I want that Ant is using my custom wxs file. How Do I do that?

I did not find a clear description where to place my custom wxs file. I placed it under my project `\build\Package\Windows\test.wxs`.

But output is stating:

> Config files are saved to C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler5060494280971686435\windows. Use them to customize package.
>
> Using default package resource [WiX config file] (add package/windows/test.wxs to the class path to customize)

My folder structure looks like this:

```
project
  src
    ressources
  build
    build
      classes
      libs
      src
    package
      windows
        test.wxs
    build.xml
```

What do I have to do, that my custom wxs file is used???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem . while,I used inno setup to build setup.exe file .

My solution is writing my own inno setup script based on javafx script which found in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler5dss886329843971686435\windows, then writing an another ant task depends on fx:deploy task that I execute the innosetup script in command line like blow:

```
<target name="do-mydeplopy" depends="do-fxdeploy, prepare-deploy">

    <exec executable="iscc">
        <arg value="my-deploy.iss"/>
    </exec>

</target>
```

You should learn how to write the setup script.

Comment: I came to this solution also. But I want to do it understandable for the user and robust too. When I add some new Ant Tasks nobody knows why I am deploying the application twice. First with fx:deploy and afterwards with executing wix Candle and Light separately. In the meantime I found how to configure ant to know where the wxs file is placed. You just have to define the path in ant classpath. I will come back to your solution when my other ideas are not working. :)